# how to add source file recursively in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

How to add all files in some sub-directory in qt project file.
for example, my source tree is:

- src

  - app/

    - foo/
  - ui/
  - common/

Now I add all files like this

```
SOURCES +=  ./*.cpp \
            ./app/*.cpp \
            ./app/foo/*.cpp \
            ./ui/*.cpp \
            ./common/*.cpp
```

Is there any way  to add all these files under `src` directory to `SOURCES`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the [files](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false) function:

```cpp
SOURCES += $$files("*.cpp", true)
```